# when to use python function expm1 rather than exp-1

Tags: python, function, numpy

the expm1 "function avoids the loss of precision involved in the direct evaluation of exp(x)-1 for small x."

is there a rule of thumb as to what is small? 1e-1, 1e-10, 1e-100 ?
(side Q: is there a performance or other reason not to always use expm1?)

```
np.info(np.expm1)
Examples
--------
The true value of ``exp(1e-10) - 1`` is ``1.00000000005e-10`` to
about 32 significant digits. This example shows the superiority of
expm1 in this case.

>>> np.expm1(1e-10)
1.00000000005e-10
>>> np.exp(1e-10) - 1
1.000000082740371e-10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer

If 6 significant decimal digits are enough for you, `exp(x)-1` is okay up to x being 1e-10.  In general, you are going to lose N decimal digits of accuracy when x is about `10**(-N)`. We start with about 16 digits in double precision.

Why not always use `expm1`? Because `expm1(x) + 1` has absolutely no benefit over `exp(x)`, no matter how small `x` is. It only makes sense to use `expm1` when your computation actually requires something like `exp(x) - 1`. One has to consider the wider context of the computation.

#### Long answer

It's not really about how small x is, but about how `exp(x)` is used in your computation. The purpose of `expm1` should be understood in wider context of [Loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). Some formulas are subject to loss of significance for certain ranges of parameters; one has to analyze the formula to see if and when it happens. And if there is a potential loss of significance in some range, rework the formula into something algebraically equivalent but numerically stable. Wikipedia explains this well on the example of quadratic equation.

If your goal is to compute `exp(x)`, or `3*exp(x) + 4` or such, you should use `exp`. There is no loss of significance here, and no benefit of putting `expm1` in such a formula, regardless of how small `x` is. Writing `expm1(x) + 1` instead of `exp(x)` is entirely pointless.

If your formula is `exp(x) - 1` or `exp(x) - cos(x)`, then there is potential loss of significance for small `x`. This is not always a reason to rewrite; if you only plan to use this formula when x is 1 or more, there is no issue. If you are okay with *absolute error* being at machine epsilon level (1e-16 or so), and don't care much about *relative* error, there is no issue.

When the loss of significance occurs, it's up to the ultimate user of information to decide how much loss is acceptable. Often, getting 6 significant digits is quite enough for practical purposes, so losing 10 decimal digits out of double precision accuracy may be acceptable then. In this context, the formula `exp(x) - 1` incurs unacceptable loss of precision when `x` is smaller than `1e-10`. Indeed, the value of `exp(x) - 1` is close to `x` but `exp(x)` looks like 1.00000000... with 10 digits after dot being 0; so only 6 digits remain from x itself.

Rewriting functions in a numerically safer form requires some human effort, to work out whatever algebraic or trigonometric identities are needed. Examples of such rewriting:

```
f = lambda x: np.exp(x) - np.cos(x)
g = lambda x: np.sqrt(x**2 + 1) - 1
```

Numerically safer form of the above:

```
f_safe = lambda x: np.expm1(x) + 2*np.sin(x/2)**2 
g_safe = lambda x: x / (np.sqrt(x**2 + 1) + 1)
```

Rewriting `np.exp(x) - np.cos(x)` as `np.expmp(x) - np.cos(x) + 1` would have no benefit at all; one has to think through the entire computation to eliminate the subtraction of nearly-equal numbers.